# How to get One2Many list from Many2Many list elements (3 levels) in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a module with some entities: Activities, requests, purchases and bills
Many activitiy have many requests, many request have many purchases(orders) and each purchase has one or more bills (a bill belong to aone purchase). How can I get from the Activity entity a list of all the bills related to that activity?

```
class ActivityCenter(models.Model):
    _name = 'center.activity'
    _rec_name = 'Activity'

    request_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='center.request',
        string='Request',
        inverse_name='activity_ids')


class RequestCenter(models.Model):
    _name = 'center.request'
    _rec_name = 'Request'


    activity_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='center.activity',
        string='Activities',
        relation='center_activity_request',
    )

    purchase_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='center.purchase',
        string='Purchases',
        inverse_name='request_ids')

class PurchaseCenter(models.Model):
    _name = 'center.purchase'
    _rec_name = 'Purchase'

    request_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='center.request',
        string='Request',
        relation='center_purchase_request',
    )

    bill_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='center.bill',
        string='Bills',
        inverse_name='center.bill')

class Bill(models.Model):
    _name = 'center.bill'
    _rec_name = 'Bil'

    putchase_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='center.purchase', string='Purchase')
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I just edited the post cause I had the relations wrong. The issue is that I want to get all the bills related to an specific activity (An activity should have an lists of all the bills related to ot). Bills and activties are on the other side of the chain, Activity is related to request, request is related to purchase and purchase is related to bill.

Comment: Loop over `request_ids` to get `purchase_ids` then use it to get all the `bills`.

Comment: Thanks you so much but that would at least 4 nested "for" lioops. So I desided to run a SQL querry that gets a list of all bills for that activirty, then return it in a new view. Would it be more efficient that running all those loops? Thanks anyway

Comment: In the first approach, the ORM will browse data and make it available for you, Of course, the execution will be faster using SQL query since you just need the get bill ids.You mentioned "an other view", are you considering using [Potgresql view](https://github.com/itpp-labs/odoo-development/blob/master/docs/dev/py/postgres-views.rst)?